# conditional rendering of a array and a filtered version of the array with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am trying to render an array of elements in react so that when you hover over an element it then filters the array of elements and re-renders with just the hovered element. Keeping position is buggy but not the worry for now.

It works but when the hover element is rendered it has no content

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const cards = [{key:"1",title:"elem1",content:"..."},{key:"2",title:"elem2",content:"..."},{key:"3",title:"elem3",content:"..."}]

const tempCards = []

My hover function returns

tempCards = [{key:"1",title:"elem1"}];

/// temp function allowing to work from button click
const changeShow = () => {
    tempCards = cards.filter(item => item === cards[0]);
    console.log(tempCards[0])
    setShow(!show)
  }
```

This is all working as it should but then when the element loads on the page no content shows

```
    {show ? cards.map((item)=> {
      return <CardSpinLeft
         onClick={toggle}
         key={item.key}
         id={item.key}
         image={item.img}
         name={item.title}
         title={item.title}
         paragraph={item.content}
         />
         }): 
         <CardSpinLeft
         onClick={toggle}
         key={tempCards.key}
         id={tempCards.key}
         image={tempCards.img}
         name={tempCards.title}
         title={tempCards.title}
         paragraph={tempCards.content}
         />
      }
```

not receiving any error's I even tried making the filter function async/await thinking its a loading issue. Only thing I can think is that react is pre-loading the content before it is there?

Comment: How are you toggling show to true when there's a hover? You'll need to add a handler and use ```onMouseEnter```/other mouse events to toggle that variable.

Comment: exactly like that, so I have a onMouseEnter handler that works and filters the cards and shows the hovered card but without any content (img, title, paragraph) the image tag shows up as alt (unable to load).